# Tier-pricing for backend orders?

Tags: tierprice

It looks as though tier-pricing, if set for a product, does not get applied when ordering in the backend, only on the frontend?  It means that at present, the sales team has to manually input the price on the backend when taking an order to apply the correct discount based on tier pricing. This is for configurable products that show on the front end, but they choose a simple product (option) (e.g. flavour) when buying it.

The tier price is currently set for the configurable product only.

Anybody come across this issue and the best way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Tier prices are also applied correctly for backend orders if you add the correct products. You should not add simple products associated to a configurable product directly, but the configurable product. If you create a new order in the backend and add a new product, you can configure the configurable product:

[image]

If you click on "Configure", you can select the attribute and quantity:

[image]

If you press OK and "Add Selected Products to Order", you will see that the tier price is applied correctly:

[image]

To make a long story short, add the configurable product to the order - that is also how Magento does it in the frontend.